# Como deixar as colunas do Triângulo de Floyd perfeitamente simétricas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo para formar e exibir um `Triângulo de Floyd` com `n` linhas.

O código se encontra logo abaixo:

```
n = int(input(f'Digite o número de linhas: '))

m = 1
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    for i in range(1, c + 1):
        print(m, end=' ')
        m += 1
    print()
```

Ocorre que quando **n <= 3** as colunas são exibidas perfeitamente simétricas, tal qual o resultado...

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6
```

Porém, se **n > 3** as colunas começam a se apresentarem `desalinhadas`. Exemplo, `n = 5`...

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

Como poderia organizar as colunas do Triângulo de Floyd para para que as mesmas se apresentem simétricas (devidamente ordenadas) para todo **n <= 40**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você só quer até n igual a 40, o maior valor possível é 820, então uma opção é alinhar os números à esquerda, ocupando 4 posições.

Para isso, basta usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) disponíveis:

```
m = 1
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    for i in range(1, c + 1):
        print(f'{m:<4}', end='')
        m += 1
    print()
```

No caso, `<4` diz para alinhar o valor à esquerda usando 4 casas, preenchendo as posições não usadas com espaços em branco.